# How to understand effect of a variable

Tags: machine-learning, probability, distributions, conditional-probability

I have two variables x and y. x takes values from $A=\{1,2,3..16\}$ and y takes values from $B=\{b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4\}$. I am trying to understand if knowing the value of y helps to know anything about the value of x or vice versa.

So far, I have plotted $pdf(x=i|y=b_j) \forall j$ against $pdf(x=i)$ and tried to understand if anything is different. What would be a formal way to approach this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can try a scatter plot to see if there is any relation. However, given your pdf plot I am not sure if that would yield a better insight.

The other approach you can take is a logistic regression. For that, do the following:

1. Use x as your input and y as the output (since y has only 4 possible discrete values). Check the coefficient of x and its statistical significance. You can use either R or Python (statsmodel package, scikit logistic regression will not provide p-value) for getting this significance value (p-value). If the p-value is less than 0.05, then the coefficient (can be considered) significant.
2. If the coefficient is statistically significant, take exponential of the coefficient of x. It would give you odds ratio.
3. If this odds ratio is way larger (say, 1.8, 2 etc) or smaller (say, 0.5, 0.1 etc) then you can say there is a strong relationship between x and y. However, bear in mind that this relationship may not be causal.

Comment: Thanks. But x is a categorical variable.

Comment: Does not matter. Use one-hot encoding to represent x in the input. You can still run a logistic regression. If you have 16 possible values of x, and logistic regression gives you "influential" coefficient then you can (naively) summarize that those particular value of x has some influence on y.